# Ruby regex for fluentbit

Tags: regex, ruby, fluent-bit

I need to create a regex expression for fluent bit This is what I tried

```
^(?<log_time>[0-9-]+ [:0-9,]+)\s+\s+(?<severity>\w+)\s+-\s+(?<message>.*)
```

Input is `2022-07-20 15:21:31,994 - INFO - Moving to Dashboard`

Desired output:

```
    log_time:  2022-07-20 15:21:31,994
    severity:  INFO
    message:   Moving to Dashboard
```

How can I achieve this? (at some point I am getting the log_time before milliseconds but that's not enough)
Help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try `^(?<log_time>[0-9-]+ [:0-9,]+)\s+-\s+(?<severity>\w+)\s+-\s+(?<message>.*)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/QDPqYB/1))

Comment: Your pattern tries to match characters that are not there, like the starting `[` and the `T`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, appreciated, Can you please share any best cheat sheet to learn regex.

Comment: Here are lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), you can also read through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: If i change the event to this type `2022-07-20 15:21:40,345 [I]: brc.py:118 - Moving to FLB ` 

i tried making expression this way `^(?<log_time>[0-9-]+ [:0-9,]+)\s+(?<severity>[\w+)+]:\s+(?<codeline>[\w]+[.0-9,]+[:\w]+)\s+-\s+(?<message>.*)` here the only issue i can see is the with `[I]` can you please have a look and i guess it can be improved as well.
@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/QDPqYB/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?<log_time>[0-9-]+ [:0-9,]+)\s+-\s+(?<severity>\w+)\s+-\s+(?<message>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QDPqYB/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<log_time>[0-9-]+ [:0-9,]+)` - Log time: one or more digits or `-`, then a space, and then one or more colons, digit or commas
- `\s+-\s+` - a hyphen wrapped with one or more whitespaces
- `(?<severity>\w+)` - Severity: one or more word chars
- `\s+-\s+` - a hyphen wrapped with one or more whitespaces
- `(?<message>.*)` - Message: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (no need of `$`)